# Functional Dependence: Как сделать decomposition?

Tags: база-данных

Пусть `ebay_prod_vendor = (prod_id, price, model_num, vendor, delivery_price, storage)` - схема отношений. И пусть Functional Dependence будут:

> prod_id -> price model_num
>
> vendor storage -> delivery_price

Требуется разлоэить

Разложите `ebay_prod_vendor` в (набор) relational схем через декомпозицию без потерь ***(lossless-join decomposition)*** и объяснить, почему это действительно декомпозиция без потерь **(lossless-join decomposition)**(а именно, покажите, что критерий декомпозиции без потерь, описанный в классе, сохраняется на вашей схеме).

Задача с экзамена в одном из Британских ВУЗов. Как это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант ответа:

т.к. `prod_id` должен быть в двух разделенных "схемах" (sets| *R1 n R2 = prod_id*), и удовлетворять `prod_id -> price model_num`, то получаем:

> R1 = (prod_id, price, model_num);
>
> R2 = (prod_id, vendor, delivery_price, storage);

далее разделим R2 на `R3 n R4 = vendor storage` (исходя из условия 2).

> R1 = (prod_id, price, model_num);
>
> R3 = (prod_id, vendor, storage);
>
> R4 = {delivery_price, vendor, storage}